# How to alias a class method within a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, extending

I am using Ruby v1.9.2 and the Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 gem. I had the following module

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.my_method(arg1, arg2)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

and I wanted to alias the *class method* `my_method`. So, I stated the following (*not working*) code:

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.my_method(arg1, arg2)
      ...
    end

    # Note: the following code doesn't work (it raises "NameError: undefined
    # local variable or method `new_name' for #<Class:0x00000101412b00>").
    def self.alias_class_method(new_name, old_name)
      class << self
        alias_method new_name, old_name
      end
    end

    alias_class_method :my_new_method, :my_method
  end
end
```

In other words, I thought to extend the `Module` class someway in order to add an `alias_class_method` method available throughout `MyModule`. However, I would like to make it *to work* and *to be available* in all my Ruby on Rails application.

1. Where I should put the file related to the Ruby core extension of the `Module` class? Maybe in the Ruby on Rails `lib` directory?
2. How should I properly "extend" the `Module` class in the core extension file?
3. Is it the right way to proceed? That is, for example, should I "extend" another class (`Object`, `BasicObject`, `Kernel`, ...) rather than `Module`? or, should I avoid implementing the mentioned core extension at all?

But, *more important*, is there a Ruby feature that makes what I am trying to accomplish so that I don't have to extend its classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `define_singleton_method` to wrap your old method under a new name, like so:

```
module MyModule
  def alias_class_method(new_name, old_name)
    define_singleton_method(new_name) { old_name }
  end
end

class MyClass
  def my_method
    puts "my method"
  end
end

MyClass.extend(MyModule)
MyClass.alias_class_method(:my_new_method, :my_method)
MyClass.my_new_method     # => "my method"
```

Answering your comment, you wouldn't have to extend every single class by hand. The `define_singleton_method` is implemented in the `Object` class. So you could simply extend the `Object` class, so every class should have the method available...

```
Object.extend(MyModule)
```

Put this in an initializer in your Rails app and you should be good to go...

Comment: I didn't test your code yet, but by using that I have to extend all classes / modules where I will need to run the `alias_class_method` method. Is it inefficient (since I can do the same with Ruby Metaprogramming) and not DRYed?

Comment: I have still some doubts on the "worthiness"-"effort" of your approach: could / should I use a "Open Class" approach in order to accomplish what I would like to make? *why not?*

Comment: Well, I can't really answer that because you didn't say what exactly you need it for... IF you need the "Open Class" approach to accomplish  what you have to do, then there won't be any other way I'm afraid, since the simple 'alias_method' only works on instance methods. But the question for me is: Why do you need to alias class level methods? Which particular case? I always go with the narrowest approach, meaning if I need the certain behavior to work in a whole class tree use the top class, if 2 child trees in the whole tree, use the base classes of the 2 child trees...

Comment: +1 because after I tried many googled examples (maybe outdated?) that's the one that worked for me at least. `3.times{ puts "thanks!" }` (ruby-2.0.0-p195)

Comment: Does anyone know how to make this work in a chaining fashion? (à la the popular Rails method [`alias_method_chain`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/alias_method_chain)) If you simply define a new method that calls the old one and then redefine the old one, you will call your new method instead because of late binding. Edit: Is this it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408136/how-can-i-dynamically-define-an-alias-method-for-a-class-method

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on this website: http://engineering.lonelyplanet.com/2012/12/09/monitoring-our-applications-ruby-methods/

The solution is to use [`class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) with a block. That enables using variables from the enclosing scope.

```
module Alias

  def trigger
    @trigger = true
  end

  def method_added(name)
    if @trigger
      @trigger = false
      with_x = "#{name}_with_x"
      without_x = "#{name}_without_x"
      define_method(with_x) do
        "#{send(without_x)} with x"
      end
      alias_method without_x, name
      alias_method name, with_x
    end
  end

  def singleton_method_added(name)
    if @trigger
      @trigger = false
      with_x = "#{name}_with_x"
      without_x = "#{name}_without_x"
      define_singleton_method(with_x) do
        "singleton #{send(without_x)} with x"
      end
      singleton_class.class_eval do
        alias_method without_x, name
        alias_method name, with_x
      end
    end
  end

end

class TestAlias

  extend Alias

  trigger
  def self.foo
    'foo'
  end

  trigger
  def bar
    'bar'
  end

end

TestAlias.foo # => 'singleton foo with x'
TestAlias.new.bar # => 'bar with x'
```

If you don't have [`singleton_class`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) then you should probably upgrade your version of Ruby. If that's not possible you can do this:

```
class Object
  def singleton_class
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer was confusing and did not work.

```
class Module
  def alias_class_method(new_name, old_name)
    define_singleton_method(new_name, singleton_method(old_name))
  end
end

module MyModule
  def self.my_method
    'my method'
  end
end

MyModule.alias_class_method(:my_new_method, :my_method)
MyModule.my_new_method # => "my_method"
```