# How can I dynamically define an alias method for a class method?

Tags: ruby

I have a module lets call "Calculator" that I want to include in a class "Product".  Calculator will extend "Product" which will copy the class methods onto Product.  One of these class methods is "memoize".  The idea being that I can do something like this:

```
module Calculator
  def self.extended(base)
    base.memoize :foo_bar
  end
end
```

With the purpose of memoizing the method (specifically a class method) :foo_bar.  Inside of memoize I call the method "alias_method" which attempts to alias a class method to a different name (here :foo_bar).  This fails.  Memoize looks something like:

```
module Calculator (the extended module)
  def memoize(name)
    alias_method "memoized_#{name}", name
  end
end
```

When this is called via memoize :foo_bar, the alias_method line kicks an error saying Product has no method "name".. my understanding is this is because alias_method will attempt to alias instance methods not class methods.. (I don't know why but ok no big deal)..

I can reopen the eigenclass like so

```
module Calculator
  def memoize(name)
    class << self
      alias_method "memoized_#{name}", name
    end
   end
end
```

This would work but name is not available to the scope of the class << self definition.  People have mentioned using self.class_eval and self.instance_eval but neither of these seem to work.. I'd like my cake and eat it too.. how can I keep alias_method dynamic but use it on class_methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So just learned that this will do the trick:

```
module Calculator
  def memoize
    define_singleton_method(name, method(name))
  end
end
```

Then when Calculator gets included in Product it will define the singleton method as I needed.  I still don't know why alias_method needs to only work on instance methods.. and I don't know why class_eval or instance_eval didn't solve the problem.. but at least I have a solution..

Answer (score 3):

What if you put the instance method to be aliased before the include/extend?  If you're putting the extend right after the class name, the instance method will not yet have been defined.

```
module Foo
  def self.extended(base)
    base.memoize :flavor
  end

  def memoize(name)
    alias_method "memoized_#{name}", name
  end
end

class Bar
  def flavor
    puts "Orange"
  end

  extend Foo
end

if __FILE__==$0
  b = Bar.new
  b.memoized_flavor   #=> Orange
end
```

Comment: While a good thought this actually wasn't the situation as the method that was to be aliased was extended in the module and was extended before the attempted aliasing.  Great thought though.